# how to create a "byte stream" from different data type in python

Tags: python, byte

Here is a little problem: I want to create a byte stream (a table of byte integer) from different data type, integer of variable length, string.

```
val1 = 0x2
val2 = 0x0001020304050607
val3 = "blablabla"
```

And I want to obtain a stream like:

```
byteStream = val1 + val2 + val3
byteStream = [0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x62, 0x6c, 0x61, 0x62, 0x6c, 0x61, 0x62, 0x6c, 0x61]
```

I have tried several things, like using a intermediate string and then convert this in byte. But this solution is ugly, and does not work properly.

Any help welcomed.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import struct

val1 = 0x2
val2 = 0x0001020304050607
val3 = "blablabla"

data=struct.pack('>BQ9s',val1,val2,val3)
print repr(data)
```

yields

```
'\x02\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07blablabla'
```

`BQ9s` tells `struct.pack` to pack one unsigned int (1 byte) , followed by one unsigned long long (8 bytes) followed by 9 chars (1 byte each). The list of possible format characters can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#format-characters).

`data` is a string (that is, a sequence of bytes). If you wish to ultimately have a list, you could use `list(data)`.

Comment: where are methods to_bytes and from_bytes I did not found on the dic

Comment: @Xavier Combelle: [to_bytes](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) is new ... introduced in Python 3.2